# iOS app freeze after setting text larger in accessibility mode

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin.ios

The app works normally when I set **Settings>Accessibility>Display & Text Size>Larger Text** to **OFF** or **ON with default value**.
However when I try to make the Text Size larger even a little bit, the app UI freeze at that moment,

My Home page includes `UIRefreshControl, UITableView, UICollectionView`. This issue is reported on iOS 14.6, iPhone 11 Pro Max & the standard version.

The app is built in Xamarin.iOS, using Mvvmcross framework

Comment: Isolate the problem. If your Home page is an empty page, does it still happen? If not, add features one at a time, until you find exactly what breaks it. Once you've found it, make the simplest possible page that freezes. Then edit your question, show the XAML of that page. If that XAML has any `Bindings` to a ViewModel, then do the same to the ViewModel source: strip it down to the simplest possible version that freezes, and add that .cs to your question.

Comment: Thanks Toolmaker, I think I edited the tag incorrectly, this is a Xamarin native project , but I isolated the problem to a `UIView` containing an FFLoadingImageCache with property that makes the whole view freeze when enlarge the text